# Use custom map arcGIS on android

Tags: android, gis, arcgis

I am using arcGIS android API to create a android based map application of my university. The problem that I have is that I don't know how to load up a custom map with layers from a shapefile and thus I cannot progress with the application. If anyone can tell me how that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ShapefileFeatureTable` and `FeatureLayer`. Follow the example at https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-demos-android/blob/master/2015-DS/DevSummitDemo/DevSummitDemo/src/main/java/com/esri/android/devsummit/DevSummitDemoActivity.java :

```
try {
        mTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(filePath + fileExt);

        mFlayer = new FeatureLayer(mTable);


        // Set renderer based on geometry type

        if (mTable.hasGeometry()) {

          if (mTable.getGeometryType() == Geometry.Type.POLYLINE) {

            mFlayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.YELLOW, 0.50f)));

          } else if (mTable.getGeometryType() == Geometry.Type.POLYGON) {

            mFlayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent))));

          } else if (mTable.getGeometryType() == Geometry.Type.POINT) {

            mFlayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.YELLOW, 1, STYLE.CIRCLE)));

          }

        }


        mMap.addLayer(mFlayer);

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (Exception e1) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Adding Shapefile has failed, please restart app to add shapefiles.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e1.printStackTrace();

      }
```